# Kibana 4.4.2 Environment variable in config file

Tags: ruby, yaml, kibana

**Edit** For anyone wanting updates, here is a link to the issue I created to hopefully get this added:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6688

When I setup Elasticsearch I can have entries in the config file that reference environment variables (this is on RHEL - Linux):

`var.name: ${ENV_VAR}/something`

This works for Elasticsearch.

I want to do the same for Kibana:

`logging.dest: ${ELK_HOME}/log/kibana.log`

Problem is, in this case I get an error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '${ELK_HOME}/log/kibana.log'
    at Error (native)


Finished
```

Any ideas how I make the Kibana `kibana.yml` config file use environment variables?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: I have not found one.`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: See my edit, I created an issue on github with the project.